# Common name for a group of commands which break the linear structure of the program

Tags: programming-languages

I'm looking for a name of a group of all commands which are break the linear structure of the program.

In `C` PL, they are: `goto,return,break,continue`. `C++` also contains `throw`.

`Perl` has `last,next,return`.

Is there a common name for those groups of commands? Where can I read about those kind of commands?

Comment: I can't think of anything completely appropriate. Perhaps "(special) control flow commands". For some of them "early exit" would be fine. Also "jumps" covers some of them. "control operator" is the right term for `call/cc`, but it could also be applied to `if` and `while`.

Answer (score 6):

These are control flow statements. There is a quite a large list of them on their [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow).

Comment: Except that those also include statements for structured flow control such as `if` and `while`.

Comment: @reinierpost As they should be. They break the linear structure of the program.